# Exiting batch script after it starts

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, informatica

I have this batch script:

```
C:\{Directory}\PsExec.exe -u {UserName} -p {Password} \\{IP_Address} /accepteula "C:\batchfiles\{BatchScript}.bat"
```

And the {BatchScript}.bat script is:

```
C:\{Directory}\infacmd.bat wfs startWorkflow -DomainName {Domain_Name} -ServiceName {Service_Name} -UserName {Username} -Password {Password} -Application {Application} -Workflow {Workflow} -wait
```

This script kicks off an Informatica process to build a data warehouse (not sure if that's important, but thought I would mention it). When I run the first batch script, it kicks off the second batch script. However, it seems like command prompt waits for Informatica to be finished before it exits. My issue is that I have other processes that need to run, and this process takes 5 hours currently. Is there a command I can add on to my second (or first) script that will exit command prompt immediately after it kicks off? I don't believe this will impact the data warehouse build since I don't need Windows to monitor the process.

Comment: Call a batch file like `call "batch-file.bat"` from another one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
start "windowtitle" C:\...whatever...\infacmd.bat w....
```

should do what you want...

Comment: What do you mean by "windowtitle"?

Comment: It's the title that will be displayed at the very top of the window while the process is running. The `start` instruction uses the very first "quoted string" as the title of the window. The title can be empty of you wish, and if there are no "quoted arguments" then it can be omitted entirely. Downside is that if you later add a quoted argument, `start` will use that as a window title and not provide it as an argument to the process.

Comment: OK. So by adding this to the second batch script, it will immediately exit the command and not monitor it?

Comment: It will proceed to the next statement in the batch file. The `infacmd.bat`... process will run in its own context. If there are no further statements in the batch file, that procedure will terminate. On termination, if it was `call`ed from a batch file (with a `call` command) then it will resume the batch from which it was called. In your case, since it's executed by `psexec`, the `psexec.exe` will continue to do whatever it does (probably terminate, so *that* batch continues to the next step).

Comment: Thanks! I'll test it out!